# Обработка button по нажатию на кнопку enter

Tags: jquery

Необходимо чтоб кнопка button нажималась, по нажатию на кнопку enter.
Сразу хочу сказать кнопка находиться не в форме
Помогите пжл написать, шарил гугл не чего толкового не нашел

Answer (score 2):

По идее, когда фокус остановлен на кнопке и нажимается `enter`, событие `onclick` тоже должно срабатывать, но если вы настаиваете:

```
$('#button').keyup(function(){
    if(event.keyCode==13)
       {
          $(this).click();
          return false;
       }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Поможет метод [.trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/), [.keyup()](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) и [event.which](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/). Собираем всё воедино и [получаем такую картинку](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/t6wxF/).

P.S. Но меня не покидает ощущение, что вам не столько надо вызвать событие клика на кнопке, сколько выполнить какое-нибудь действие, которое происходит при обычном клике по этой кнопке.